# Why can't I see the 'dataset project' property in Visual Studio DataSet designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, dataset

I am trying to follow 'n tier app design' tutorials and they tell me to set the DataSet Project property from the Data Set Designer in VS, to split table adaptors and entities into seprate projects. I can't see that property! (I'm looking in the same place shown on the videos... all other properties match)

Does anybody know why?

The video  is here http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=14625 (4:36 is where the property is set)

I'm using VS c# 2008 Express, with SQL Server Express 2008.

Thanks a lot for any help

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the DataSet Project property is not available in the express edition.

Comment: Or *fortunately*, depending on your opinion of DataSet projects. :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis, I agree completetely, but you've got to start somewhere, and it is tough when you can't follow along with the tutorials.

Comment: OK... am I following a path of pain by trying to use DataSets? All my other .NET projects have been ASP. I am trying to set up a new App with WinForms (so adopted the MS 'n tier' approach, with DataSets, as described in the video above), but no longer sure the 'best' approach. Any advice, or pitfalls to be aware of? Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan, it is not necessarily a path of pain -- I think DataSets have their place. Many experienced developers turn up their noses and deride the use of DataSets, not acknowledging that they used to use them too. DataSets were a big deal in the early days of .NET, and it is pretty hard to see their shortcomings until you've got a fair bit of experience. So, I'm not going to tell you to shy away from DataSets. You could easily land on projects in the future that already use them, so it is worth knowing. Just remember there is more out there, and keep learning. No coasting in this industry.

Comment: @Ryan, I see that you tagged your question with entity-framework. EF is an object-relational-mapper, which is an alternative to DataSets. I think a logical path through the Microsoft technology stack as you learn about persistence is DataSets -> LINQ-to-SQL -> Entity Framework.

Comment: @Jay, a great help - thanks a lot for the advice and your time; much appreciated. DataSets here we go...